# Uppercase for reference to a itemize

Tags: enumerate, labels

I want to write in uppercase the value of a \ref.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{textcase}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*]
     \item \label{i:1} hola
     \item ujeuj
\end{enumerate}

The value for option hola in capitals is \MakeTextUppercase{\ref{i:1}}
\end{document}
```

In this case the answer is

```
The value for option hola in capitals is a
```

and I want it to be

```
The value for option hola in capitals is A
```

I have also tried with \MakeUppercase, but no way. Any help? I don't want to change the ref font on the whole document, just for this case. And of course I don't want the option using `\Alph` at the `enumerate` as I want the enumerate to be lower case and the other upper case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reference should enable the reader to find the reference. If the item is labeled with `a` then the reference should be `a` and not `b` or `1` or `A`.

This said you can try to expand the \ref first. In your example it works, but if you load e.g. hyperref you will get undefined references.

```
 \expandafter\MakeTextUppercase\expandafter{\ref{i:1}}
```

A bit better is to use a small caps font:

```
\textsc{\ref{i:1}}
```

The best is imho to create a second label:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{textcase}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*]
     \item \label{i:1}\makeatletter\def\@currentlabel{\Alph{enumi}}\label{uppercasei:1}\makeatother hola
     \item ujeuj
\end{enumerate}

The value for option hola in capitals is \ref{uppercasei:1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can it be with hyperref? BTW fix the first expand after.

Comment: I doubt that with hyperref it can be done without a lot trouble. But I added another suggestion which should always work.

Comment: I have accepted this as you linked me to currentlabel option which I can use in many other places ;) The other solution is cleaner for enumitem.

Comment: I thought you wanted the uppercase `\ref` only in one place and only for one item and not for the specific enumerate, as you wrote that you "don't want to change the ref font on the whole document, just for this case." That's why I didn't suggested the enumitem solution.

Comment: you are right... yours helped. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

You can just add   `ref=\Alph*` in the options:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{textcase}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*, ref = \Alph*]
     \item \label{i:1} hola
     \item ujeuj
\end{enumerate}

The value for option hola in capitals is {\ref{i:1}. 

\end{document}
```

[image]